# Stylings added to a react-native view does not work correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

**Problem:**

I have created a react native application and there the styling added to a one of styling does not work correctly.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  Image,
  ScrollView
} from "react-native";
class Finelist extends Component {
  onContentSizeChange = (contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
    // Save the content height in state
    this.setState({ screenHeight: contentHeight / 3 });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={StyleSheet.fines}>
        <View style={styles.finelistHeader}>
          <Text style={styles.finelistHeaderText}>{this.props.title}</Text>
        </View>
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
          onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSizeChange}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.payButton}></TouchableOpacity>
        </ScrollView>
        <View>
          <View>
            <View style={styles.fineTitleContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.fineTitle}>None-use of seat belt</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={1}
                style={styles.payButton}
              ></TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fines: {
    flex: 1
  },
  finelistHeader: {
    backgroundColor: "#ff9a00",
    paddingLeft: 30
  },
  finelistHeaderText: {
    color: "#ffffff",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 14,
    marginTop: 17,
    marginBottom: 17
  },
  fineTitleContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor:"#000000"
  },
  fineListContainer: {
    flex: 1
  },
  fineTitlePayContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  payButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#27a000"
  },
  fineTitle: {
    fontWeight: "600",
    fontSize: 14,
    letterSpacing: 0.64
  }
});
export default Finelist;
```

I am using It like this in the homepage.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
  StyleSheet,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  Image,
  ScrollView
} from "react-native";

import SummuryCard from "../Shared/SummuryCard/SummuryCard";
import FineList from "../Shared/Finelist/Finelist";

import QRCode from "react-native-qrcode";

import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      text: "0xC925F1698DCFB85F4F4A9235A23A7E8F"
    };
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.homeHeader}>
          <View style={styles.homeHeaderImage}>
            <LinearGradient
              colors={["#fdc830", "#ff9a00"]}
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                alignItems: "center",
                borderBottomLeftRadius: 80

                //   overflow: ( Platform.OS === 'ios' ) ? 'hidden' : "visible"
              }}
            >
              <View style={styles.hederContentContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.homeHederText}>Thomas Mullar</Text>
                <Image
                  source={require("../../../assets/user.png")}
                  style={styles.image}
                ></Image>
              </View>
            </LinearGradient>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.qrCodeGeneraterContainer}>
          <QRCode
            value={this.state.text}
            size={150}
            bgColor="black"
            fgColor="white"
            fontWeight="600"
          />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.viewDetails}>View Details</Text>
        <SummuryCard></SummuryCard>
        <FineList title="Pending Fines"></FineList>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    top: 0,
    flex: 3
  },
  homeHeader: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    flex: 1
  },
  homeHeaderImage: {
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  homeHederText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontStyle: "normal",
    fontFamily: "sans-serif",
    letterSpacing: 0.81,
    color: "#000104",
    marginTop: "2%",
    marginLeft: "40%",
    marginRight: "3%"
  },
  hederContentContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: "10%",
    marginBottom: "10%"
  },
  qrCodeGeneraterContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  viewDetails: {
    color: "#ff9a00",
    fontSize: 12,
    marginLeft: "79%",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginTop: "5%",
    marginBottom: "3%"
  }
});

export default Home;
```

But styling added to all views on after fineTitleContainer does not work correctly.

This is where I am facing the issue.

```
<View>
              <View>
                <View style={styles.fineTitleContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.fineTitle}>None-use of seat belt</Text>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={1}
                    style={styles.payButton}
                  ></TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
```

So can Someone help me to solve this problem.I tried lot to find a solution to this problem but I was not able to do so. Thank you!

Comment: Please be specific about the question in which part exactly you feel the pain. No one will read the whole 200 line of code and ponder out the fault.

Answer (score 0):

you should change

```
 <View style={StyleSheet.fines}>
```

to

```
 <View style={styles.fines}>
```